# Is there a c# windows form Application in visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015, and tried to create a windows form, just as I used to do it in the VS2010. I could not find a Windows form for C#.

How can I create one? Do I need to install another version or do I need a plugin or something?

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8rwzyl

Informations about my Visual Studio: http://prntscr.com/8rx0a1

Comment: Under Installed-->Templates-->Visual C# there is Windows Forma Application for me.

Comment: You are likely missing the template. However, I recommend you learn WPF which is a much better experience (though a much steeper learning curve)

Comment: I imagine you just left out something during your install, which can easily be fixed, but I don't know what component you would have missed off the top of my head.

Comment: @JohnieKarr yeah i saw a tutuorial where there is one too but... look at my screenshot. why is there no one for me.... i really need some help

Comment: @DavidG i don't really have time to learn it right now because i have to get that little programm done, but i will learn it later, thanks for the advice. Do you know how i can get a wf for now?

Comment: That isn't visual studio in your screen shots. It is Blend which is used for WPF applications. I don't use the community version, but they are two seperate applications

Comment: That's **Blend**, not full Visual Studio, search for & download *visual studio community 2015*

Comment: The screenshot shows "Blend", not Visual Studio

Comment: You're looking at blend dude. It's not visual studio

Comment: Under Templates-->Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are opening new project in `Blend`. You have to use `Visual Studio` (not Blend).

`Blend` and `Visual Studio` are installed together with `Visual Studio Community Edition 2015` . You probably run a wrong shortcut (which starts `Blend`).

Comment: thank you but... i have literally no idea why i have the blend version. i have a dreamspark account and i got it from there, i think it's the only one i can download, no idea why tough. thank you anyways

Comment: @Econ the Full Community edition is free: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

Comment: @Econ Make sure to accept the answer if it helped solve your problem. GL

Comment: yeah i am still working on it. it's not working atm, you said that they are both being installed(the blend version and the normal one) but i do ONLY have the blend version. weird. I am currently updating it and installing everything again. will accept your answer as soon as it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Checked Answer is correct however there is no explanation of how to solve this. I just came to the same problem, but figured it out. When searching in your file directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE

Then you can search .exe and it will come up with Blend and devenv. Or just scroll till you find devenv.  devenv is the clickable application for visual studio community. :)